# Set Max Number of Created Threads for Java application using Linux

Tags: java, linux, multithreading

I am running a Java application under Centos and curious on the ways you can set the limit on the max number of threads **created**. Please don't confuse with the max number of threads at one given time.

For example, everyday an application creates and destroys one thread. Is there somewhere in the Linux settings where I can set that only 250 new threads can be created. Then somewhere before day 250 (earlier because of other threads created) it will crash (throw exception) because it has reached the allowed limit of new threads created.

Comment: Are you talking about *kernel-level threads* or *Java-level threads?* Not all Java threads are assigned a kernel thread.

Comment: Also, what specific exception are you getting? It seems like you'd have to create a ton of threads to get an error like this. And what Java version are you using?

Comment: We are using Java 8. The reason for asking this question is we got an application in our production environment that started throwing an unable to create new thread runtime error. We know from monitoring it that the app only had 120 threads at the time. Since we never got this error in testing I'm trying to see if some kind of setting in the Linux environment could have created this. We are constantly creating and destroying threads but never have to many at one time running. So the setting of both kernel-level threads or Java-level threads would be applicable.

Comment: Which implementation of Java 8 are you using? There may be a command-line flag to control this.

Comment: It is not being set by a command line flag. That I'm sure of.  

[root@edd ~]# java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: Hmmm. What specific error are you getting? Can you provide a stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux only enforces resource usage, not resources ever used (apart from total CPU consumption)

You can do this from Linux by adding an [endorsed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/standards/) library to define your own `ThreadGroup` or `Thread` class.  This could be added to the JVM in such a way that you don't need to alter your application and it could use an environment variable to set the limit.

This would still require a little coding up front, but the JDK is a development environment.

Comment: Ok, this backs up some simple programs I have written to test and what I have gathered from researching on the Internet. I just couldn't find anywhere where it explicitly stated that Linux doesn't enforce "resources ever used".

Comment: @DavidR If they stated this, they wouldn't be able to offer this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly make your own `ThreadFactory`, something like

```
public class LimitedThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {

    public LimitedThreadFactory(final int limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    public Thread newThread(final Runnable runnable) {
        if (numberOfThreadsCreated >= limit) {
            // exit gracefully
        }
        // create the thread, maybe with new Thread(runnable);
        numberOfThreadsCreated++;
    }

    private final int limit;
    private int numberOfThreadsCreated;
}
```

Comment: For my specific case, I'm curious how to set it within the Linux environment.

Comment: I suppose you could pass it as a java command line parameter. -Dyour.program.threadlimit=250, then just pass your new `ThreadFactory` around to objects that create threads.

Comment: Thread.getId() is a count of the number of threads.  You could stop when you reach `getId() > 250`